# ios7 UILabel in UICollectionViewCell does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Deployment target 7.0,
Running on iOS7.1,
Xcode 5

I have a UIImageView "comicImage" and UILabel "comicTitle" set up using IB on the UICollectionViewCell.

comicTitle uses these settings:

[image]

The IBOutlet is properly hooked up.  The view cell is properly registered to the collectionView. I have output the title in

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

on the console and the text of the title did get assigned to comicTitle.

When I run the app, comicImage shows up, but comicTitle does not show up.  I have ensured that the alpha of comicTitle is set to 1.0.

This same piece of code worked in a previous app with deployment target set to iOS6.

I have no idea what went wrong.  Can anyone shed light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     UINib *comicStripCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ComicStripViewCell" bundle:ni];
     [_comicStripCollectionView registerNib:comicStripCellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"comicStripCell"];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     ComicStripViewCell *comicStripViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     comicStripViewCell.comicTitle.text = @"This is a title";
     comicStripViewCell.comicImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thisImage.png"];

     NSLog(@"comicStripViewCell.comicTitle.text = %@", comicStripViewCell.comicTitle.text);

     return (UICollectionViewCell *)comicStripViewCell;
}
```

I do not think it is a problem with the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "The view cell is properly registered to the collectionView"? It would be helpful if you could post the whole cellFroItemAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Why do you use registerNib instead of creating a prototype collection view cell in storyboard? Also, when returning your cell from cellForRow, you don't need to cast it, assuming `ComicStripViewCell` is subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. Any chance the cell it too small and the `UILabel` is displayed out of bounds?

Comment: I am not using storyboard.  You are right about the casting at return.  I do not need to cast it.  I checked the cell's size, the whole cell is visible on screen, just that the label does not show.

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the view cell is too small.  I checked again and this is indeed the problem.  I changed the UICollectionViewFlowLayout item size and the label is showing now.  Your deduction is correct and I have marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: I forgot there is no check mark here and I cannot actually checked it as the correct answer.  Anyway, thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions.

1. Apply a background color to check where your label lies
2. Mess with the label frame values. Give a trial and error and see whether your label has been misplaced somewhere.
3. If you have used constraints make sure you have given the specific constraints correctly.
4. Check whether your comicImage is not overlapping your label
5. You can actually see a preview of your xib in xcode(i.e, After you designed your cell you can confirm how your cell will actually display in the screen). Refer the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You got me thinking about the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  I have changed the size of the image and forgot to change the item size of the flow layout.  The flow layout still has the old item size.  After fixing the item size, it is fine now.  I have up vote your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by given the tag value below code is the sample code for UILabel tag approach

1. In storyBoard Drag the UILabel from the Object library in to the collection view cell
2. Give the Tag value 30 to UILabel from the Attributes Inspector
3. Get the UILabel object from the below code

write the below code in the Collection view DataSource method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
     ComicStripViewCell *comicStripViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *comicTitle = (UILabel *)[comicStripViewCell viewWithTag:30];// get the UILabel object by its tag value
    comicTitle.text = @"testing"; // assign the value that you want for comicTitle
 return (UICollectionViewCell *)comicStripViewCell;
}
```

otherwise share the piece of code that you have.
may be your label frame has been misplaced somewhere.
Please check UILabel Frame also

Comment: Nonono! Don't get used to doing viewWithTag. Just create a subclass with IBOutlet property. Also, don't use magic numbers like `30`, declare a constant for it.